# Personas can not Found. Kentico 8

Tags: kentico

I enabled content personalization in settings. I also have EMS Kentico. But i can't found personas in application. What could it be.

But if I trying open Personas from page I see it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTrl5.png)

Comment: I resolve this problem. It was necessary to include it on the site through the Modules

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the Personas module to given site. Go to Modules -> Personas and on the Sites tab add the current site.